# How can I mount a TV to drywall on acoustic channel?

Tags: technique, wood

I bought a house and it has this super awesome movie room.   When I moved in, I took my stud finder out and it wasn't working on that side of the wall, but it was working on the other side.  I took the recessed power plug off the wall and looked inside to find the studs are actually 1 to 2 inches back.  **The drywall is not tight to the studs...**  I do not want to hang a 65 to 75 inch TV on drywall.  This seems like a recipe for disaster.

So the question is: How do I do this?

Some ideas are:

1. extend the studs or possibly secure another 2 by 4 to the side of the studs that are already there, then redo that portion of the drywall
2. Cut out a rectangle of the drywall and attach a 2 by 4 to the front of the studs so it's like a "T".  If I can get the right size piece of wood then that could be flush with the wall and can be painted to match the black wall.
3. something that you guys think of

This needs to be able to support a 75 to 100 pound TV mounted to it.  This makes me nervous and I don't know what the best practices would be.

If I go with #2, should I glue it on, then add some nails or screws to attach it to the drywall better?  I can't clamp the 2 by 4 to the studs so I'm not sure how effective that would be.

Comment: Just on anchoring into studs vs. the drywall itself (on a wall built conventionally) you **can** most definitely hang a large TV directly from drywall with half-decent fixings. Tests have shown that direct pull-out resistance (not shearing, which is most of the real-world force being resisted) of *each* one of a commonplace drywall anchor can be enough! This is the typical situation when you can hang a large framed picture with glazing for example..... now obviously you won't use just one, so say the weight is distributed over four screws you'd have absolute peace of mind.

Comment: It really depends on the quality of drywall in question, and the sorts of anchors used. I have a house that uses a combination of plaster and lathe and "plasterboard" with a modern addition that has ordinary drywall. The drywall has aged so poorly I hate doing anything in that room, and there is no way I'd trust it to hold much if I couldn't reach a stud in a few places. Over the years I've collected anchors and techniques that are good for each of the wall types I have, but the trial and error was more like trial and swearing for some time.

Comment: "The drywall is not flush with the studs" Is it? One construction technique for stopping sound transmission through walls is to have offset or staggered studs. If you happened to pick a spot where the studs were against the opposite wall, you might have missed the actual studs.

Comment: I just ordered an endoscope so I can look inside the wall.  All I know is that my stud finder works perfectly on one side of the wall and completely fails on the other.  That and when I looked in there, the stud I could see wasn't touching the drywall.

Comment: Looks like i forgot to update this.  I was right.  The studs are a few inches behind the drywall across the entire wall.  There is some sort of metal framing going horizontal on the top and bottom that hooks into the studs and one in the middle that seems to just be there for support, but isnt hooked into the studs.  I ended up getting some short 2x4s and gluing/screwing them into the studs.  Figured between the wood glue and 5 screws in each 2x4 it'd stay up fine.

Comment: @Migit thanks for coming back to update us. Please post your _comment_ down below as an _answer_, then give yourself a check-mark. That way, others with this issue will know that this question has been resolved and can look to it as a source of knowledge.

Comment: This is a community maintained question and answer board. Posting here automatically grants rights to _anyone_ to edit your question. Edits are moderated to ensure they don't change the question beyond what the OP intended, even if it's the OP who makes said change.

Answer (score 3):

That wall system is a “sound control” system. There are special metal framing members running perpendicular to the studs. They are secured to the studs that allows an air space between the wallboard and stud.

The metal stripping is called “RC-1 channel “. You can google it.

Answer (score 1):

The gap between drywall and studs may be to help with soundproofing - the solid stud to drywall connection conducts sound much better than a thinner connection - but there must be something *somewhere* holding up the drywall.

You really have a number of possible fixes. The variation is basically how much wood, how much drywall and how much patching/painting. Since this will be covered by a TV, plywood plus a couple of coats of black paint should work quite well - it doesn't need to be the kind of perfect smooth finish of a regular wall since nobody will be looking directly at it.

- Pick a rectangular area going across at least 2 studs (typically 16" apart) that will be covered by the TV. You can drill small pilot holes with a long bit to make sure you can get to the studs so you don't rip apart the wall in a bad spot.
- Cut a strip of drywall horizontally from one stud to the next with the height matched to the width of the wood you are going to use (e.g., 3-1/2" for 2x4). Measure the depth needed to get from the studs through the drywall. If it is a 1" gap + 1/2" drywall then 2x4 (1-1/2" thick) will work perfectly but if the gap is bigger then you will need thicker wood or two layers.
- Cut 2x4s (or other wood) to length and screw into at least two studs.
- Repeat at a second spot lower (or higher) on the wall at least a few inches away but preferably close to the full height of the TV.
- Cut a piece of plywood just big enough (perhaps an inch or two larger all around) to cover the 2 strips of wood.
- Paint to match the rest of the wall.

The great thing about plywood is you can screw into it anywhere - you no longer have to worry about whether you are over the studs. This is normal for mounting telephone & networking equipment in wiring closets and will work well for mounting TVs too.

Answer (score 0):

You are guaranteed to have studs behind the drywall.  How else would the drywall stay in place?  Take a rare earth magnet and run it along the wall until you hit a drywall screw or nail or if you can see a slight dimple in the face of the drywall you'll know a stud is there.  Probably as other people have noted this is a party wall and there are two sets of studs, one for your side and one for the other side, that help with noise transmission.

You could use toggle bolts and likely never have a problem with 75 pounds, if you look on the packages they rate each toggle at 40lbs of direct pull our or 75 pounds if the force is perpendicular.  I personally wouldn't go that route.  I'd find a stud and set my mount to it.  If the stud doesn't sit where you'd like to center the tv then either go with the sheet of plywood that is secured to the studs or open the drywall and add a cross piece.

Comment: The studs are a few inches behind the drywall across the entire wall.  There is some sort of metal framing going horizontal on the top and bottom that hooks into the studs and one in the middle that seems to just be there for support, but isnt hooked into the studs.  I ended up getting some short 2x4s and gluing/screwing them into the studs.  Figured between the wood glue and 5 screws in each 2x4 it'd stay up fine.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same concern but it was aty work so I really wasn't too concerned.  We hung a huge 62" tv on the wall directly on drywall and it has been fine for a few years now

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/158785)